# Associate ` to <S-dead-grave> in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

**What do I have to write in my `.emacs` file in order to associate the `<S-dead-grave>` command with inserting the character `` ` `` (backtick).**

I run GNU Emacs 23.1.1 on Unix.

Background: I run Unix via a shell that runs in Java (Oracle SGD) on a Windows terminal server. I do not have admin access on either system. My keyboard is set to Norwegian. There is apparently some bug in Java causing this to act weird with "dead" characters (like `` ` `` is on the Norwegian keyboard) and I have not succeeded in getting my administrator to fix this.

When I click `` ` `` followed by a space (as is the way to insert that character with my keyboard layout) in Emacs, I get the error message `<S-dead-grave> is undefined`. Hence, I believe that if I could define this, I would be able to work around this error.

Within this setup, I am also happy with alternative workarounds.

Comment: What happens if you type the ` character on the terminal, without emacs?

Comment: Good question. In the shell, as well as in Stata's less-than-usable built-in editor, it appears that  \`+space is interpreted as \`. So \`+space = nothing, \`+space+space = \`, \`+a = à, \`+space+a = à. This is not the case in Emacs, probably because the \`+space is intercepted before anything else happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not completely clear to me whether you run Emacs in GUI mode or in text mode (in a terminal emulator), but based on your description of Emacs's behavior I guess it runs in GUI mode (maybe via some X server on your Windows machine?).

It's strange that you'd get S-dead-grave events, so it might be a bug in your GUI environment (your X server's config?).

But in any case

```
(global-set-key [S-dead-grave] "`")
```

might let you work around the problem.

Comment: Thank you! That worked like a charm. Yes, it is in GUI mode, the SGD shell has some sort of X server (I think it runs in Java). I do not have this problem on another computer on which I can login to the same Unix system with a different X server (which I do not have admin privileges to install in this Windows system).  I might add a new question about finding a "portable" X client to install, there are several minor bugs with this one...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and [this bug report discussion](https://bugs.launchpad.net/emacs-snapshot/+bug/1251176) reports a solution :

```
XMODIFIERS= emacs
```

I did put it into my `.bashrc` after testing that it works (with `XMODIFIERS= emacs && emacs`)

This is apparently not needed with emacs 24.4, but I use emacs 24.3.1 and still need it.

Answer (score 0):

If `XMODIFIERS= emacs` works for you (*don't forget space after equal sign)*, check `~/.xinputrc` and `/etc/X11/xinit/xinputrc` or run `im-config` and select `none`. For more info consult debian reference chapter [I18N and L10N](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch08.en.html)